# jquery trying to grab button position by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

So I have some buttons name add_subpage0, add_subpage1 and so on... then an onclick to function. example:

```
<input type="submit" name="add_subpage0" value="Add Subpage" onClick="popup_subpage('add_subpage0');">
<input type="submit" name="add_subpage1" value="Add Subpage" onClick="popup_subpage('add_subpage1');">
```

Im trying to grab the position of the button and move a div to said position. The only problem (I think) is getting the name of the button.

```
<script>
function popup_subpage(thisdiv) {
    var name = 'div[name=' + thisdiv + ']';
    var thebutton = $( name );
    var popupdiv = $( 'div[id=add_subpage_popup]' );
    var position = thebutton.position();
    popupdiv.css("visibility", "visible");
    popupdiv.css("top", position.top);
    popupdiv.css("left", position.left);
}
</script>
```

The div (add_subpage_popup) becomes visible. But the position isnt changed. I think its not even grabbing the button by the name I set. 
Any thoughts? Im at a loss.
Zach

Comment: Why does your `input type="submit"` have a `value`? Also, why is that `onClick` and not `onclick`.

Comment: Why don't you just write `onclick="popup_subpage(this)"`. Then the function will receive the button element directly, instead of having to search for the name.

Comment: And `div[id=add_subpage_popup]` should be `#add_subpage_popup`.

Comment: Is this inside a `<form>`? Clicking on a submit button will submit the form and reload the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name = 'div[name=' + thisdiv + ']';
```

should be

```
var name = 'input[name=' + thisdiv + ']';
```

since the name is on an `<input>` element, not a `<div>`.

```js
function popup_subpage(thisdiv) {
  var name = 'input[name=' + thisdiv + ']';
  var thebutton = $(name);
  var popupdiv = $('div[id=add_subpage_popup]');
  var position = thebutton.position();
  popupdiv.css("visibility", "visible");
  popupdiv.css("top", position.top);
  popupdiv.css("left", position.left);
}
```

```css
#add_subpage_popup {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="add_subpage0" value="Add Subpage" onClick="popup_subpage('add_subpage0');">
<input type="submit" name="add_subpage1" value="Add Subpage" onClick="popup_subpage('add_subpage1');">
<div id="add_subpage_popup">
  Popup
</div>
```

Comment: Such a silly mistake on my part. It works now! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just pass **this** in the function and you automatically get the element to work with.

```
<input type="submit" name="add_subpage0" value="Add Subpage" onClick="popup_subpage(this);">

function popup_subpage(thisEl) {

    var thebutton = $( thisEl );
    var popupdiv = $( 'div[id=add_subpage_popup]' );
    var position = thebutton.position();
    popupdiv.css("visibility", "visible");
    popupdiv.css("top", position.top);
    popupdiv.css("left", position.left);

}
```